# Steam Big Picture Mode Inverting the white spots with black

Tags: steam

I really don't know how to fix the problem, that's why i'm asking the community here for help, I tried the Steam Community but no one responded, so i'm asking the question here:

This is my problem:

[image]

I really hope someone can help me fix this problem.
Here is some information about it:

> Steam is installed on an external hard drive with all the games with
>   it
>
> I happen to switch between computers with my hard drive, on all other
>   pcs or laptops i have opened this particular Steam install, i never
>   got that problem, except for my laptop here where Big Picture Mode
>   acts weird

Comment: As a curious question, what is the concern here? The text seems perfectly legible. Are you certain this isn't simply a theme issue or something similar?

Comment: no i don't install steam skins and yes you can read text of course, bpm isn't suppose to look like this @Anaksunaman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...Even tough nobody helped me, I managed to solve the problem, I simply updated my graphics card drivers which where 10 year old (literally), so yeah sometimes updating might be the solution to your problems.

It now works fine.